# Deploy React Project to an external server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, webpack, web-deployment

I want to upload my React project to an external server. I already have a project and I use node server locally to run it using webpack.
*I don't have any deployment experience prior to this. So any insights regarding deployment would be helpful.*

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

- `SSH` to the server using server credentials.
- sudo su
- git clone `repository address` [*Only if the repository hasn't been cloned yet*]
- cd `projectFolder`
- git checkout `<branchYouWantToDeploy>`
- git pull origin `<branchYouWantToDeploy>`
- npm install
- npm run build:production
- `apachectl graceful`    [*only for apache servers*]
- `service nginx reload`  [*only for nginx servers*]
- exit

If `git` and `npm` are not installed in the server, you can follow these links respectively:

GIT

> https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

NODE

> https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/ 
> npm is installed with Node.js 
>  npm is distributed with Node.js- which
> means that when you download Node.js, you automatically get npm
> installed on your computer.

*You may/may not need to follow all the steps depending upon the type and complexity of your project and server. However those should be good enough to start. You can always add more details regarding your project and deployment server in your question.*

Here are some medium blog post that might you to go in-depth:

> [Understanding React deployment](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-deployment-5a717d4378fd)
>
> [Deploy react-webpack to Digital Ocean with Nginx and Github](https://medium.com/@cameronbwhite90/deploy-react-webpack-to-digital-ocean-with-nginx-and-github-b83d1cf4be0b)

Comment: depending on the server they may also need to install git and node.